# undefined method `enum' for #<Class:0x007f099c303390>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using in rails and getting following error:

```
undefined method `enum' for #<Class:0x007f03202a1190
```

Model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

   enum status: [ :current, :preffered ]

end
```

How can i remove this error.

Comment: Is `enum` a reserved key maybe?

Comment: I want to use rails enum module like >>http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? Because enums are supported since version 4.1.

Comment: I see. Can you edit your question and post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: what do mean by stacktrace? i am trying to use enum api of rails,this is the line in model because of which i am getting this error.

Comment: Sorry it just come to my mind, there's no such a thing as rails 4.2 (see http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions). Did you mean 4.0.2? In that case, you don't have enums yet.

Comment: I hope you have a column status in your migration of Location table ?

Comment: Edge guides document the new APIs in the master branch, but not necessarily in the most recent gem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Enum` was only introduced to Rails at [`commit db41eb8a`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/db41eb8a6ea88b854bf5cd11070ea4245e1639c5), and so far this commit has only been released with Rails tag [`v4.1.0.beta1`](https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v4.1.0.beta1).

It's likely that the current Rails gem you're using does not yet have this commit, and so does not have the code for implementing `enum`.

To check to see which version of the Rails gem you have, run:

```
bundle show rails
```

I just ran `bundle update` and then `bundle show rails`, and I am showing:

```
[PATH TO YOUR GEMS]/rails-4.0.2
```

This version of the gem does not include the code with `enum`.  You can see this by [comparing what is in `v4.0.2` with what is in `v4.0.1.beta1`](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v4.0.2...v4.1.0.beta1).  If you click on 'File Changed' and then do a search in the page for `enum.rb`, you'll see that that is completely newly added code.

If you want to ensure that you get the newly tagged version of Rails, you can modify your Gemfile so that your line for including rails looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :tag => 'v4.1.0.beta1'
```

After you do a `bundle update`, you can see by doing a `bundle show rails` that you have the following rails gem:

```
[PATH TO YOUR GEMS]/rails-f706d5f945c5
```

[`f706d5f945c5`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/f706d5f945c5751072bb90d080aff154e6858435) is the commit that was tagged for release `v4.1.0.beta1`.

After you get this bleeding edge version of the Rails gem, you should have access to this `enum` functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this feature by copying the code in [the file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e3ceb28e66ca6e869f8f9778dc42672f48001a90/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb) `rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum` plus these lines:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    extend ActiveRecord::Enum
  end
end
```

to your app's `lib/` directory and then `require`-ing it in your `environment.rb` file. Eg.: in `config/environment.rb`

```
require 'active_record_enum'
```

You may refer to [this code](https://github.com/openstax/accounts/blob/b42ca91b63c79b4ae8a1b8a6c7eb88fcdfeb65c5/lib/active_record_enum.rb) we have in production.